# How to capture a click on elements using partial IDs with vanilla Javascript?

Tags: javascript

I want to run a function anytime one of a series of elements are clicked and want to target these elements using a partial ID.  Currently, only the first element responds when clicked upon.  What have I done wrong?  My code:

HTML:

```
<div>
    <a id="selector-0">Zero</a>
</div>
<div>
    <a id="selector-1">One</a>
</div>
<div>
    <a id="selector-2">Two</a>
</div>
```

JS:

```
document.querySelector('[id^="selector-"]').onclick = function(){
    var id_selector = this.getAttribute('id');
    alert('ID: ' + id_selector);
}
```

I have attempted changing the querySelector to include 'a[id^="selector-"]', but only the first element ever wants to respond on click.

Comment: Why not use a className selector or a tagName selector for A within the context of the wrapping element??

Comment: That's exactly how `document.querySelector()` is meant to work; try using `document.querySelectorAll()` and iterate over the returned`NodeList`.

Comment: Are you trying to do something like JQuery does where you can listen to events for every element that matches a selector, even if that element is created later (or it's attributes change so that it now matches the selector)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `*=` selector with `id` as attribute and `document.querySelectorAll`.

Then add the `onclick` to all the elements of the given array of retrieved elements.

```js
const els = Array.from(document.querySelectorAll('[id*=selector-]'));
console.log(els.length);
els.forEach(el => el.onclick = () => console.log('Clicked el:', el));
```

```html
<div>
    <a id="selector-0">Zero</a>
</div>
<div>
    <a id="selector-1">One</a>
</div>
<div>
    <a id="selector-2">Two</a>
</div>
```